# how to disable mail while user register in drupal 7 programatically

Tags: php, email, drupal, drupal-7

I am using drupal commerce for my shopping cart project and when a user register to drupal site a mail is fired to the user mail id. But In my project when a user buy a product (and if he is not registered ) he is redirect to the registration page and after register he will automatically log in to the site and redirect to the cart page . I have performed all the scenario except when user is registering a mail is sent to its mailbox which I do not need if the user buy a product before his registration

Here is my code

```
function user_verify_user_insert(&$edit, &$account, $category) {
  // Make sure that this rule only applies to users not
  // being created by admins. Also, if admin approval is
  // required, further verification would be useless.
  global $user;

  $order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
$quantity_total = 0;

if ($order) {
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);


   foreach ($wrapper->commerce_line_items as $delta => $line_item_wrapper) {
    $quantity = $line_item_wrapper->quantity->value();
    $quantity_total = $quantity_total + $quantity;
  }
}


  if (
    !user_access('administer users', $user)
    &&
    variable_get_value('user_register') == 1
  ) {
    $udata = new stdClass();
    $udata->uid = $account->uid;
    drupal_write_record('user_verify', $udata);
    if (
      (int)variable_get_value('user_verify_delay') == 0
    ) {
      _user_verify_send_code($udata);
    }



    if (variable_get_value('user_verify_lock') && _user_verify_load($account) && $quantity_total==0 ) {
        // modify the user's DB entry
        $account->status = 0;
        db_update('users')
        ->fields(array('status' => 0))
        ->condition('uid', $account->uid, '=')
        ->execute()
        ;
    }
   if ($quantity_total > 0) {

    $account->status = 1;


        db_update('users')
        ->fields(array('status' => 1))
        ->condition('uid', $account->uid, '=')
        ->execute()
        ;
     _user_verify_cleanup($account);
    $user = $account;
    $form_state['uid'] = $account->uid;
    user_login_submit(array(), $form_state);

  }     


  }
}


function user_verify_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{

    if($form_id==user_register_form)
    {
        $form['#submit'][] = 'user_verify_register_submit';

        unset($form['simplenews']['newsletters']);
        //$form['simplenews']['newsletters']['#attributes'] = array('checked'=> 'checked', 'style'=>'display:none');

    }


}

function user_verify_register_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
    $account = $form['#user'];
    if ((int)$account->status == 1) {


    $order_id = commerce_cart_order_id($account->uid);
    if ((int)$order_id > 0) {
        $form_state["redirect"] = url("checkout/" . $order_id); 

    }       

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can alter the mail with [hook_mail_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) and set **send** to **false**.
ASD